Venom that ages survivors: Any suggestions?
I'm writing a story that features tons of mythical beasts, all of which are commonly called "demons" by the general public, even though the term "demon" is more analogous to how we use the term "fish", at least in this universe. One such species I'm working on has the power to physically age your body in some form. I'm thinking of having it be a subspecies of basilisk or cockatrice.
In this universe, basilisks and cockatrices are rare, and have venom known for causing some absolutely ruinous effects to the human body. While I am handwaving some aspects of demon biology, particularly the ones that are effectively supernatural, most of the anatomical and biological anomalies of said demons is at least partially understood in some fashion. So, don't feel bad if you can't get me anything especially concrete. We have some wiggle room here!
There is a character who encountered a basilisk, got effectively pepper-sprayed by the bastard, endured a long recovery period that left him weak, and was left with his skin and hair prematurely aged by the ordeal.
I am still debating what kind of effect this particular venom has, especially since it has the side-effect of aging tissues.
Basilisk and cockatrice venom varies by species, and the effects range from paralysis and rapid necrosis to outright turning living tissue to bone, so I guess I'm trying to think of something that would not only end in aging survivors prematurely, but still had a similarly wild effect.
For the record, this guy is still pretty physically capable. He can still do his normal job, which is physically demanding, just a little less than he used to. After the recovery period, he was left with less muscle and thinner skin, but otherwise he is still able to handle the arduous task of monster slaying, he just takes weaker targets than he used to. If you think any other health problems could come up, kindly let me know! I could use the feedback!
Also, this is my first post on here, so let me know if I'm doing something wrong, yeah? Cheers!
EDIT: I only brought up the flesh-to-bone thing as a way of illustrating some examples of what kind of things basilisk venom can do to the human body. Paralysis and turning-tissue-to-bone are basically two extremes of the spectrum here.
As for what I mean by the term "aging", I mean something that would induce effects that mimic your body getting older. Degenerative tissues, wrinkled skin, grey hair, etc. This should be something that is at least partially recoverable, but still leaves you weaker and visibly (seemingly) older than you were before you got attacked by a basilisk.

(1) Hair is not living tissue. It cannot age in any meaningful way. (2) Bone is living tissue. (3) Turning flesh into bone quickly is magic, because there is nowhere for the calcium to come from. (4) Any life-threatening trauma has long lasting effects. Nothing special is needed. (5) Asking for suggestions is not usually considered on topic.

Aging is a cluster is interrelated symptoms whose cause and progression aren't all that well understood. There isn't likely to be one chemical root cause that you can bottle up in a venom, but equally, if you simply say that that's the effect it has, it isn't as though we know enough about the underlying condition to say "no it isn't".

-1 for lack of research. I googled "chemical that causes premature aging" and the first result was an article, "The Chemical Exposome of Human Aging" discussing what appears to be the very information you're looking for. Per the [ask] page, you're expected to do your due diligence before asking here, which is why brainstorming is discouraged in the [help/on-topic].


I clearly misspoke, I didn't mean to imply hair was living tissue. 2.) I didn't say I was asking for input on the bone thing, that was just an example of hangwaving


1.) I clearly misspoke, I didn't mean to imply hair was living tissue. 2.) I didn't say I was asking for input on the bone thing, that was just an example of handwriting. And, lastly, I honestly wasn't sure how to word the question to Google because I wasn't only looking for things that age skin. I was looking for something more along the lines of "if you got sprayed with venom, what kind seems most likely to age you physically after recovery?", which didn't seem to get me much. Though I am sure part of any mistakes made here likely came from me posting this at 3AM before going to bed.

While it isn't turning skin to bone, Calcinosis cutis causes calcium buildup in the skin and subcutaneous tissues. You could have the monster carry a disease with similar effects with them. Which will affect the person getting doused in their spit/venom.

@AlexP, Re, "Bone is living tissue." Mmmm. sort of. Bone tissue is a matrix of protein and mineral crystals that is permeated by living cells. The bone cells move through the matrix. They build it, they repair it, and under some conditions, they can re-absorb it. Apart from the mineral crystals, it's similar to other connective tissues  in your body (tendons, cartilage, fascia, etc.) I guess "ageing" in bone and "osteoporosis" mean approximately the same thing. Something triggers the bone cells to do more re-absorbing, and not so much building.

Transgenic progeria
The synapomorphy (common characteristic) of the order Daimones is the ability of their cells, particularly in their venom glands, to package exosomes (little membrane-bound bits of cells that are shed into the secreted fluid) containing a viral-like vector for transgene integration.  Over millions of years these have evolved to be substantially more effective than the gene therapy vectors available to 20th-century Earth.  They contain sequences that allow them to be targeted rapidly and efficiently to the nucleus and can do a "knock-in" replacement of host genes with few off-site effects.
The original ecological role of these constructs was in sexual selection.  The demons essentially evolved control over what normally would be a viral activity, so that they could infect potential mating rivals and partners with sequences that would improve their overall success.  Subsequently the taxonomy of this order is complicated by high levels of gene transfer.  Because the constructs can be pathogenic, parasitic, commensal or symbiotic, and each species may contain a library of constructs for various situations, the details of their system are a dream for the researcher, and a nightmare for the undergraduate.
Of course, for common people it is the constructs that target human genes which are of concern.  The fellow in this case received missense mutations to LMNA (Lamin A/C), a nucleoskeletal protein that forms a strikingly beautiful network just inside the nuclear membrane of each cell.  The result of these alterations was a severe, but localized, case of late-onset Hutchinson-Gilford syndrome with marked symptoms of progeria (localized aging).  This was not the only component of the venom - the spray caused widespread injury and inflammation comparable to tumor promoter treatment (but not tumor initiation).  Compare the effect of giant hogweed.  As a result, the cells of his dermis and epidermis underwent many cycles of replication and apoptosis during his period of 'recovery', allowing deleterious effects of the progeria construct to accumulate.  Part of this effect was that his hairs underwent telogen and fell out, and regrew at a somewhat accelerated rate without pigmentation, giving the classic appearance of gray or white hair.
The single point of mercy in this composition was that it was not optimized to circulate within the human body.  The exosomes used a cilium and acrosomal enzymes to penetrate a short distance into flesh (functions similar to spermatozoa, with a different object); but they did not survive in the circulatory system long due to clearance by neutrophils.  The acrosomal enzymes in this case break apart the desmosomes that cross-link the keratinocytes of the skin.  Secreted gradually from a storage vesicle opposite the cilium, these enzymes immediately make a small tunnel at a shallow angle, leading deeper into the epidermis.  A complex of proteins around the base of the cilium detects glycolipid, calcium, and other signals to "smell" which way to turn to proceed ever deeper into the skin, and other exovesicles, detecting these signals within the venom fluid, follow the lead exovesicle inward.  In this way, the active part of the venom requires mere instants to translocate into the epidermis, so that simply wiping away the spent venom does nothing to undo its effects.  It requires several seconds longer for the exovesicles to reach the dermal layer and hair follicles, so expeditious use of a propane torch to administer first- and second-degree burns may offer significant defense.
The petrifying demons have a similar system using ACVR1 to induce ossificans progressiva (normally abbreviated FOP, but this is not familial).  It is speculated that demons evolved both venoms as a defense against other individual demons which had incorporated genes by horizontal transfer from prey animals, such as humans.  The targeted demons may otherwise have had a selective advantage from some of the incorporated sequences.

Oh, you. I like you. You basically broke down the whole deal with demons as a branch on the tree of life with me barely going into detail (since the main topic was trying to seek out one specific ability of one specific species). You also tackled a question I didn't even get to ask yet, involving a species I haven't even mentioned to anyone, just from the incredible amount of observation you did. I may be new around here and feel uncertain as to if I'm doing things "right", but at least I know I came to the right place to ask these questions.

This is one of the best answers I've seen, great job! This is well put and well thought out!

As a lay person, I have no idea which parts of this answer are drawn from our universe, which are merely inspired by our universe, and which are completely made-up.  Which is what makes it such a great answer.

Fiction (for now, but maybe doable someday):  Attaching cilia to exosomes, providing them with a small 'acrosome' to store enzymes, enzymes to break down desmosomes and enter the skin, the glycolipid-sensing complex, and Daimones of course.  Not fiction: the underlined links and the diseases associated with them, tumor promotion, giant hogweed, 'knock-in' constructs.  Not specified: the time delay needed for the venom to have an effect, and how the ecology of organisms capable of weaponizing gene targeting constructs in sexual selection would work, because I have no idea. :)

Autoimmune Trigger:
The venom combines with a normal human protein to trigger an auto-immune inflammatory disease akin to that caused by gluten in Coeliac's disease. The "venom" could even be a microbe or virus that triggers a similar reaction in non-demon species. The immune system would attack the underlying substructure of skin and muscles (including smooth and cardiac muscle)  An acute phase would involve severe inflammation and debilitating damage to tissues. Once the trigger (venom) had fully passed from the body, there would still be long-term tissue damage that could be partially reversed. But especially if there was damage to the heart, the person could have permanent reductions in endurance and thus also to their ability to maintain muscle mass.
A second exposure to the same venom could easily be fatal, since the immune system would already be primed to recognize it as foreign and induce a massive and immediate response.

A great answer full of great ideas! Love it, thank you!

Hydrogen peroxide
This oxidizer chemical is used for bleaching hair and etching (particularly metal and glass). As a result it can absolutely
Instant aging
Coming into contact with high proof peroxide will cause atrophy in the skin leading to white dead skin. Extended exposure will trigger inflammation that results in scarring.
When in contact with hair it breaks down melanin leading to bleached white hair. When in extended contact with skin it may cause hair loss.
Pneumonitis
Inhaling peroxide particulates damages the lungs, which causes the oxygen content of red blood cells to drop and take long to heal and manifests in extreme fatigue. This in turn leads to cyanosis, dark blue-purple skin especially mouth and extremities (also associated with age-related cardiovascular issues).
Disfiguring corpses
Peroxide is a weak acid. It does break down tissues but not likely to the bone. It will however disfigure the body due to bleaching out the color and may preserve corpses in this state serving an abhorrent sight close to the creature's lair.

Burn out (or long covid or similar)
A stress venom could induce burn out symptoms, causing lethargic behaviour. This leads to muscle loss and not being able to do all they could, without losing the abilities.
Stress
Stress is an incredible mechanism. It is too much to explain here. In short, it prepares the body for a wide range of situations. A vigorous activity, damage, sickness. The stress response allows animals to survive.
That being said, it can have big side effects. Humans have one of the most robust stress responses in the animal kingdom. Most other animals aren't so lucky. There is even a theory about exhaustion predation, where animals (humans) keep tracking and moving after another animal. The repeated high stress response can exhaust and even expire the hunted creature. As a real world example of the power of stress, my young nephew once was excitedly screaming and pointing at the aquarium for quite some time. The next day half of the fish were dead.
In humans the effects of high stress are very different per person. Some can handle it for decades before something like burn out happens. Others can get it in a month or so. Of course burn out isn't fully understood, but the immune system seems to be a big contributor. It isn't benevolent. It is a ruthless killer that needs to be tamed, or it'll tear the body apart. Too long a high stress response and you'll damage your own body too much, as well as deplete some important resources. Seeing long Covid up close with several people it is remarkably similar to burn out, so it might have a lot of similarities from the cause as well.
Stress venom
A stress venom would be perfect. It is developed by the creature as it kills or exhaust so many other creatures. Though during the fight it wouldn't take the protagonist down, the venom could be long lasting. The venom can use stress and the immune system to exhaust and damage the infected body. Much like long Covid it could then become a debilitating sickness in a few days thanks to the continued stress response of the body. A high stress response can not only exhaust your body. It can also prevent you from sleeping, or having a normal digestion. All reasons the protagonist can feel weak and frail.
I do not know if high stress can lead to ageing, though I've read about it in literature, which could have been a way to convey the damage done on the inside. My experience with a twin where one had higher stress than the other did show the stressful one getting more grey hairs earlier, and during high stress they can look older thanks to less care of themselves.
Stress does affect people differently, so you'll have a lot of wiggle room. People with burn out or similar still can do anything they did before, though the effort for them is so much higher that it can be an insurmountable barrier. Your protagonist might be one of the people not too severely affected.
Conclusion and TLDR
Stress can be a great way to make people weak and tired, even though they are physically practically unchanged. The venom can introduce stress effects of the body that initiate something related to burn out pr long covid, causing the protagonist to become lethargic. They might visibly age from it as well. From this your protagonist will probably lose muscle mass and not being able to do all the things they want, just from requiring rest.

You should have watched your young nephew more closely after he cooled down at long last: next thing he did was to pee in the aquarium.

I don't know if I'll use the stress venom for this specific species, but I am absolutely going to use it for a different species introduced down the line. Also, minor clarification: The character enduring this is not the protagonist, just someone the protagonist works with.

Notes from a Cellular Senescence Researcher
What kind of aging are we talking, exactly? When I started my research project, I was met with a somewhat similar problem: aging means a lot of things, and is ultimately such a complex process that it's hard to fully comprehend the nature of organismal "aging". Some notable hallmarks are DNA degradation, cellular senescence (my field of expertise), and telomere shortening. What you're talking about with "turning people to bone" reminds me of calcification, which can doubtless be triggered chemically.
This paper might help with what you're looking for.

The "turning flesh to bone" thing was just an example of the range of effects that basilisk species can inflict with their venom-spray. As for the aging thing, I mainly meant the kind that leads to the degenerative effects of growing older. I definitely could have phrased this question better; I think this will be the last time I ask a question at 3AM on a Sunday while waiting to fall asleep. I'm still figuring out how to navigate this site and community, mistakes are bound to happen. That paper still provides valuable input however! Thank you!

@DevilJay I'm also fresh out of the oven around here, but with general degeneration you're definitely denoting some inflammation and/or DNA degradation/reproduction adjacent business! Best of luck out there!

Nicotine
I'm not tossing around anti-smoking propaganda. This is the medical reality of how the chemical acts on our bodies.
Aging happens every time our cells divide. You only get so many cell divisions before the errors start building up. The most notorious cell division errors are called cancer. Cancer is the gears that drive our cells wearing down. If you never caught a cold, never ingested a poison, did everything right, cancer is what will kill you.
Nicotine is a stimulant in small doses and a narcotic (induces system depression) in large doses. It acts on our neurotransmitters, supplementing them, then replacing them with a less effective version. That's the part we notice.
Something else that nicotine does is kill off your cells. Not so many as hard radiation. Not like malaria, bad enough to give you anemia. It's subtle. You get chronic inflammation, increased lymph production, and a re-population of cillia cells with mucus producing cells. And, eventually, cancer.
If you want to make someone age quickly, cover them with nicotine patches. They'll get sick. Really sick. Lots of inflammation and lethargy.
If you just dose someone with nicotine, they'll flush it out of their system in hours. Do something more devious. Hit them with a molecule that binds to their acetylcholine production mechanism, have a small percentage of them shift to producing nicotine.

I unfortunately ingested a nest of Brown Tail Moths. They had not yet gone airborne. When they do go airborne, they are then called “hairs”. They exact contain venom. And there could be hundreds of hairs in a nest. A hair causes a small rash. In my case, it did considerable damage to my body. It eats tissue and attacks nerves. I’m not a doctor but I have been dealing with incredible pain for over three years now. I need to see an Odontologist to see if any of the damage can be reversed or any info and help I can find.

I'm...not sure how this relates to the topic... >_>; Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Hello Connie, thanks for this first answer on our site! It brings up a good point that the original poster (OP) probably hasn't thought about... what does it mean to "age?" If the OP is only thinking of what a person looks like (gray hair, wrinkled skin) that might be very limited. But if we consider the immobility of the body and pain, as you've described, that's pretty good insight. When you get a sec, check our our [tour] and [help] to understand us, 'cause we love people who can bring personal experience to worlbuilding.
